# Hopf-Umlaufsatz Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Does Hopf-Umlaufsatz Theorem holds for piecewise smooth simple closed curves with cusps at the endpoints?

I checked from various resources, some of them added the condition: without cusps. But from what I see from Loring Tu Differential Geometry, he didn't mention about this condition. So I only want to confirm with this. If we can remove this condition, why ?

Comment: Satz means theorem

Answer (score 1):

You can allow cusps, but there is the question whether to count them with $\pi$ or with $-\pi$. When the interior is circled counterclockwise an outward looking cusp should count $\pi$ and an inward looking cusp $-\pi$.

Imagine an "equilateral  triangle" made of circular arcs curving inwards, so that we have three cusps at the vertices. When we go around counterclockwise we obtain $-60^\circ=-{\pi\over3}$ for each circular arc. At the cusps do the following: Replace the peak with a tiny "halfcircle" on the inside. This gives you $+\pi$ at each vertex, so that in total you have $3\bigl(-{\pi\over3}+\pi\bigr)=2\pi$, as the Umlaufsatz predicts.

[image]

Comment: Why is it +pi at each vertex when we replace the peak with tiny half circle ? As in the case of equilateral triangle, Isn’t that the exterior angle at every vertices 120 degree and when I sum it up , it gets 360 degree which fits with Umlaufsatz ?